# Cannot move main Photoshop window in new install, and I want to because it's on the wrong monitor

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've finally got a new Mac (M1 Pro) and so I am now using the most recent version of PS.  Hurrah. The app opens, which is nice, and I can open a document with it, which is also nice, but I am stuck trying to move the app window to my external screen.  I can't move it by dragging it the way I am used to doing, as the main window is "stuck" on my laptop monitor.  [image: image of menu problem with menu stuck to LHS of screen, and top of application window hidden by fixed menu top of screen]

What do I mean by "stuck"?  As you can see in the screen shot, the top of the application window, which I would normally use to drag and drop the window, is hidden below the main screen menu.   I can move the RHS and Bottom of the window to resize it, but I can't get hold of it so that I can drag the whole thing to my big screen.

I am also finding the way the menus open on the LHS of the screen super disconcerting, as I find it really difficult to select items.  They often disappear before I can select them.  So I have two problems really.

I am sure this is all something really obvious.   But... what?  I've looked at the Adobe community help and found an answer from 2017 that seems related, and that has to do with selecting and deselecting application frame. https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/can-t-move-or-resize-application-window/m-p/8776832.  But I can't figure out what to do from my current situation based on that advice.

Thanks for any hints here!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately tech support is generallly off-topic here. Sorry about that.

Comment: Try doing Window -> Workspace - > Reset Essentials... or Reset whichever workspace you're using.

Comment: @BillyKerr how interesting - this what most of the questions I see here are about - if you can recommend a better source I'll be happy to use it.

Comment: Questions here really need to be about graphic design, not problem solving the use of software and hardware.  Tech support questions are difficult to answer because resolving them often requires access to your specific setup/hardware, or trial and error. Check [what is on topic on our help page](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  SuperUser might be an option for you, also there's Apple Stack Exchange.

Comment: To be clear... "How do I create X with Photoshop" is markedly different than "How to I fix Photoshop on my computer." The latter is what is off-topic here.

Comment: Or... how do i fix operating system problems. As this is clearly a mac only problem that is related to how the operating system handles this issue. Since its a mac it just works as you see here. So should be asked on a mac problems forum or superuser or something.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications about the culture on this site.  Here's what it looks like to me.  When I google a photoshop question, this site shows up very often.  And all the PS questions I see on here e.g. on Related questions, are  'how do I do X in Photoshop' questions.  Despite the name of this site, I've never seen a "real" graphic design question on it.   This must drive you totally mad!

Comment: There are an abundant amount of "how to" questions, Heather. `:)` but once in a while there are also actually more design theory questions. We've struggled as a stack to determine what is and is not permissible in terms of application-oriented questions. The easiest rule is "My Adobe is broke" is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Going into Mission Control on Apple, selecting the PS window,  and exiting it put PS in a state where I could work with it, with the app window controls visible. But this is very much a monkey at a typewriter situation. I just blundered into it.  Would love to get some context on the source of the problem, and whether this is the best way to solve it....  [image: Top menu and application window are separate]